# must construct QApp before QWidget Pyqt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qwidget, qapplication

I started new PyQt5 programme but I encounter the error "Must construct QApplication before QWidget".

I understand the error, but not find where my code constructs my QWidget first.

Here's my code:

```
class Main(QWidget):
    """ Main window """
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.business_list = ['Acheté à', 'Vendu à']

    # Pet form
    petFormGroupBox = QGroupBox("Description de l'animal")
    pet_layout = QFormLayout()
    pet_layout.addRow(QLabel("Nom scientifique:"), QLineEdit())
    pet_layout.addRow(QLabel("Sexe:"), QLineEdit())
    pet_layout.addRow(QLabel("Année de naissance:"), QDateEdit())
    pet_layout.addRow(QLabel("Cause décès:"), QLineEdit())
    petFormGroupBox.setLayout(pet_layout)

    # Business form
    petBusinessFormGroupBox = QGroupBox("Achats / Ventes")
    pet_business_layout = QFormLayout()
    pet_layout.addRow(QLabel("Nom complet + N° d'autorisation"), QLineEdit())
    petBusinessFormGroupBox.setLayout(pet_business_layout)

    business_btn_group = QRadioButton()

    for each in self.business_list:
        self.business_list.append(QRadioButton(each))

    self.business_list[0].setChecked(True)
    business_choices_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    counter = 1
    for each in self.business_list:
        business_choices_layout.addWidget(each)
        business_btn_group.addButton(each)
        business_btn_group.setId(each, counter)

    pet_business_layout.addWidget(business_choices_layout)

    hbox = QHBoxLayout()
    hbox.addWidget(pet_layout)
    hbox.addWidget(pet_business_layout)

    self.setLayout(hbox)

class Cites(QMainWindow):
    """ Cites app """
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('CITES')
        self.setWindowState(Qt.WindowMaximized)

        exitAct = QAction(QIcon('exit24.png'), 'Exit', self)
        exitAct.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAct.triggered.connect(qApp.quit)

        fileMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAct)

        toolbar = self.addToolBar('Main')
        toolbar.addAction(exitAct)

        main = Main()
        self.setCentralWidget(main)

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Bienvenue dans CITES')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Cites()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If you have any idea, I am happy!

A happy new year and enjoy your code :).

thanks per advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code wasn't indented correctly. All lines in the `Main` class after `# Pet form` should have been indented twice (i.e. 8 spaces) so that they are part of the `__init__` constructor. That way it will be executed when you create an object of type `Main()`, which should be done after after you have created a `QApplication` object.

Currently it is only indented once (i.e. 4 spaces) which means that it is part of the class definition. These lines are therefor executed during the class definition, before you create the `QApplication` object. Hence the error message.

The fix is easy, just indent the code like this:

```
class Main(QWidget):
    """ Main window """
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
        self.business_list = ['Acheté à', 'Vendu à']

        # Pet form
        petFormGroupBox = QGroupBox("Description de l'animal")
        pet_layout = QFormLayout()
        pet_layout.addRow(QLabel("Nom scientifique:"), QLineEdit())
        pet_layout.addRow(QLabel("Sexe:"), QLineEdit())
        pet_layout.addRow(QLabel("Année de naissance:"), QDateEdit())
        pet_layout.addRow(QLabel("Cause décès:"), QLineEdit())
        petFormGroupBox.setLayout(pet_layout)

        # Business form
        petBusinessFormGroupBox = QGroupBox("Achats / Ventes")
        pet_business_layout = QFormLayout()
        pet_layout.addRow(QLabel("Nom complet + N° d'autorisation"), QLineEdit())
        petBusinessFormGroupBox.setLayout(pet_business_layout)

        business_btn_group = QRadioButton()

        for each in self.business_list:
            self.business_list.append(QRadioButton(each)) # infinite recursion here!

        self.business_list[0].setChecked(True)
        business_choices_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        counter = 1
        for each in self.business_list:
            business_choices_layout.addWidget(each)
            business_btn_group.addButton(each)
            business_btn_group.setId(each, counter)

        pet_business_layout.addWidget(business_choices_layout)

        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        hbox.addWidget(pet_layout)
        hbox.addWidget(pet_business_layout)

        self.setLayout(hbox)
```

Note that the code now will hang in the following loop, because you add an element to a list while iterating through that loop. That is something you have to fix yourself.

```
for each in self.business_list:
    self.business_list.append(QRadioButton(each)) # infinite recursion here!
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. I need to find another solution for the groupbox list ;)